# How to change the timezone in Firefox using the "about:config" tab?

Tags: firefox, time-zone

What's the name of the `about:config` option that causes my browser to indicate the timezone offset? I would like to override the default value.

Comment: I can't find anything time or timezone related in about:config. Can you please explain what you are trying to do? "indicate the timezone offset" where exactly?

Comment: @DavidPostill : 1) Open [panopticlick](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) 2) Click on _TEST ME_ 3) Wait for the result 4) Click on _Show full results for fingerprinting_ 5) In the _Browser Characteristic_ column there is a row called _Time Zone_. In the 4th column you'll see a number such as `-180`.

Comment: It's nothing to do with Firefox. "The Timezone your **system** is set to"

Comment: It uses JavaScript. If you block js from eff.org you won't see any results at all.

Answer (score 4):

One setting you can check in `about:config` does affect the time zone which gets reported to web sites: if `privacy.resistfingerprinting` is set to `true`, then Firefox will always report UTC to avoid leaking information about you that could be used to generate a unique fingerprint and let web sites track you even without cookies.

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1297208